# Where css less is executing from?

Tags: css, less

In my site I don't have any LESS code or such set up but there seem to be some CSS LESS generating in my site when I check in FireFox inspector but I don't know the cause of it. Things are being generated are like:

> grid-framework.less | normalize.less | table.less | scaffolding.less

I can't unfortunately post all the code because is huge. So here are the CSS includes

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/myStyle.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.css">
```

Script includes

```
<script src="js/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/lib/screenfull/screenfull.js"></script>
```

[image]

Comment: Do you have a link to your site?

Comment: Sorry but i am working on local machine and i have no hosting set up yet

Comment: are you loading styles from any cdn?

Comment: i am not using any cdn

Comment: Do you have a .map file? If so, that's where that is probably coming from.

Comment: Alright i do have a bootstrap map file. Is it quite important for bootstrap? should i delete it?

Comment: It's not important if you aren't using LESS to process your CSS. The map file is for the exact reason you see in Dev tools. It so you can track down in your source files where the CSS styles are being compiled from. I'm adding as an answer so other people can find this.

Comment: Thank you that solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's coming from your .map file that LESS/SCSS/SASS creates once compiled. The purpose of this file is to give the original file location of the CSS styles for easier debugging and development.

You **don't need it** if you aren't using a compiler, but it is nice to have in the event you are.

Answer (score 4):

It's coming from a sourcemap reference at the end, which would look like this:

`/*# sourceMappingURL=bootstrap.min.css.map */`

The file it links to will contain encoded references to these less files.
Feel free to remove both the above line with the sourceMappingURL and the `.map` file it refers to, from your local folder.

If you're interested, here's a link explaining sourcemaps

[sourcemaps explained](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/source-maps-101--net-29173)

Comment: I dont see scss files anywhere in my development folder, the only things i have included is what ive mentioned

Comment: In what folders does you Firefox inspector say these files are present?

Comment: mysite/css/less/filesname.less but i dont have a folder call "less". Honestly it auto generating less from no where to be seen. Check my answer ive post an image

Comment: Where did you get the bootstrap file from? As suggested in a comment on your question, it might contain a source map that links to these files.