# Where is buttons.less

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to customize a WordPress theme built with Bootstrap.
The style of one of the elements is defined in button.less file (have a look at the picture). I have no such file. And as far as I can see there are no folders less and mixins.

Could you help me understand what is going on here: where is the file buttons.less?

[image]

[image]

Comment: buttons.less is one of the source files that bootstrap is built from.  You'll find the built CSS for all bootstrap elements in bootstrap.css

Comment: So, the path marked by the arrow is a fake one? Ther is no such physical file?

Comment: If you were using a source distribution of bootstrap built from LESS, then the file would be there.  Otherwise yes, it's more or less "fake".  Are you using bootstrap.css or bootstrap.min.css?  I don't get such source locations when I use the minified css.

Comment: It looks like it is bootstrap.min.css. I opened the source html of the web page, tried to find bootstrap, only bootstrap.min.css cases were higlighted (for css and js).

Comment: That information is from the `map` file. It's information that tells the browser dev tools where the CSS styles originated from. You don't necessarily have to worry about that information if you aren't compiling the original bootstrap.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where css less is executing from?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41304709/where-css-less-is-executing-from)